# How to convert this below JS code into Angular 4 code

Tags: angular

### How to convert this below code into Angular 4 code

If there is an easy way to rotate a div +90 degrees after clicking it and by clicking it next time it returns to 0 degrees

```js
$('.square').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rotate-90');
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.rotate-90 { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="square" (click)="toggle()" [class.rotate-90]="isToggled">

</div>
```

TS

```
public isToggled:boolean;
toggle(){
    this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
}
```